# How to transmit a xlsx file as a aspx response output?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel-2007, excel-2010, export-to-excel

**Goal:** Transmit a .xlsx file from server to client using aspx response output.

**Approach Tried:** 
I used same response header for all of these approaches.

1. `Response.TransmitFile(fileName);`
2. `Response.Output.Write(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(File.ReadAllBytes(path)));
   //Tried with different encodings.`
3. `Response.Output.Write(File.ReadAllText(path,
   System.Text.Encoding.Default)); //Tried with different encodings.`

**Result:**
Approach 1 worked (due to some infrastructure related constraints we cannot use this approach) . But approach 2 and 3 is not working. It's resulting a corrupted .xlsx file at client. 
Though .xlsx is collection of xml files and a binary format, I tried to open the file using notepad++ in both server and client. I noticed that they are little different.

**Question:**

1. Why the file content is getting changed after it is transmitted to client?
2. Is there any other way to send a xlsx file from server to client using aspx response output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=myfile.xlsx");
Response.BinaryWrite(File.ReadAllBytes(path));
```

Comment: Thanks @wdosanjos for your response but I cannot use Response.BinaryWrite() because of our design constraint. I have to use the Response.Output. Is there any way to resolve this issue just writing the excel to Response.Output ?

Comment: Can you use `Response.OutputStream`? Since Response.Output is a TextWriter, you won't be able to write binary data through it.

Comment: To support our legacy system we need to use the Response.Output which is HtmlTextWriter, to send xlsx file. I am wondering if it's possible or not.

Comment: As far as I know, that's not possible with HtmlTextWriter, because it can only write text not binary data.